# Pytorch が import できない

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

Macを使用しています。

Anaconda-NavigatorにてJuypter NotebookをLaunchし、ターミナルが起動し、Juypter Notebookのページが立ち上がるので、そこで新しいノートブックを作って、そこで作業している状況です。仮想環境は構築していません。

Pytorchを使いたく、インストールしたのですが、importができません。
condaを使ってインストールしても全てエラーになってしまいます。

また、google colabratory を使用してインポートを行うと全く問題なく実行されます。なぜなのでしょうか。

ご教授願います。

以下コードと実行結果になります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 質問本文は後からでも [編集] できるので、コメント欄ではなく直接追記してみてください。また、なるべくコードやエラーメッセージなどの文字は画像ではなく **文字のまま** 質問文に含めてみてください。

Comment: すみません。ご指摘感謝致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

当てずっぽうですが、おそらく複数の Python の環境が入り混じってインストールされています。まだ環境構築を始めたところであれば、一度すべての Python をアンインストールし、どれかひとつのインストール方法のみを試してみてください。

今回のエラーはおそらく、pip が期待している Python 環境と Jupyter Notebook が期待している Python 環境が異なることが原因です。pip3 コマンドが出力している `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/` というパスは Python 公式ホームページの方法で Python 処理系をインストールした際にありがちなパスですが、Jupyter Notebook は Anaconda の環境の Python を参照するように起動されていそうです。このため Jupyter が使う Python 処理系からは pip3 でインストールされたライブラリが見えていない状態になっていそうです。

また、もしこの pip3 が Anaconda のものだったとしても、Anaconda ではライブラリのインストールには conda コマンドを使うべきで、pip コマンドでのインストールと混ぜると環境が壊れがちです（[参考ドキュメント](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#using-pip-in-an-environment)）。

質問者さんは初心者とのことで、複数の環境をご自身ですべて管理するのは手間かと思います。そこでたとえば、

1. 一度すべての環境をアンインストールし、
2. Anaconda のみインストールし、
3. あらかじめ `conda install` で Pytorch をインストールし、
4. Jupyter Notebook を起動する

という流れで解決するのが早そうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。一度全てアンインストールしやり直したところ無事インポートすることができました。他のモジュールを使いたいときにも今回のように、ターミナルにて先に`conda install`を行ってから、Jupyter Notebook にてインポートを行う方が良いのでしょうか？

Comment: 今回のような使い方をされるのであれば、はい、そうです。共通の環境に対して notebook ごとにライブラリインストールを重ねていくことで再現性を高める Google Colab と異なり、手元の環境の Anaconda で仮想環境を構築しているのであればわざわざ notebook 上で毎回インストールする必要がありません。他の方と notebook を共有するようになり再現性が気になってきたら、環境をどう作り notebook をどう配布するか再考してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。大変参考になります。

Comment: 助けになったようで良かったです :) 回答横のチェックマークを押すことで回答を承認できますので、もしよければお願いいたします。過去にもいくつか質問なさっているようなので、そちらに関しても承認しておくと見やすそうです。

Comment: ご指摘感謝いたします。承認させていただきました。